# What is the accuracy of a thermocouple after calibration?

Tags: measurement, temperature, thermocouple

I'd like to use a thermocouple to create a general-purpose temperature probe.  However, the accuracy is quite a bit lower than I want.  Almost every source I look at ([example](http://www.omega.com/prodinfo/thermocouples.html)) lists the accuracy of a type-K thermocouple as being 2.2 °C or 0.75% "standard," or 1.1 °C or 0.4% "special."  (I've chosen type K for both wide range and low cost.)

On the electronics side I'm quite confidant that I can get better than ±0.1 °C, meaning that the accuracy is pretty much entirely limited by the physical probe.

Confusingly, I see some (far more expensive) thermocouple probes listed at much higher accuracy than for the thermocouple itself.  For example, [ThermoWorks lists](http://www.thermoworks.com/products/probe/tc_type_t.html) some type-T thermocouple probes as being accurate to 0.1 °C, even though the accuracy of plain type-T thermocouples is always listed as only 1.0 °C "standard," and 0.5 °C "special."

---

My thought is that I should be able to achieve higher accuracy by *calibrating* the thermocouple.  A proper ice bath (using shaved ice made from distilled water) should let me get comfortably within 0.1 °C (NIST makes ice baths repeatable to better than [0.001 °C](http://www.nist.gov/pml/upload/TN1411.pdf)).  This would let me perform a single-point calibration of the entire system (including the cold junction reference, for which I'm probably going to use a platinum RTD).  My question is, **what kind of accuracy I can expect *after* calibration?**

Another way of phrasing the question is, how much of the specified measurement error is due to random variance versus (removable) systemic error?

Comment: It is not only about the probe itself but also about how it is connected (multiple metals etc.) and how you do cold junction compensation. With enough effort you can likely calibrate it to be much better than 0.1K but that needs more than just ice bath.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm aware that all of those do affect the overall accuracy, but for this question I'm interested in how much I can reduce the inherent uncertainty from the thermocouple itself.  (Unless the stated 2.2 &deg;C accuracy is mainly due to those effects, in which case I'd like to know what the actual breakdown is.)

Comment: the stated inaccuracies are usually mostly due to imprecision in alloy composition. You should be able to create a cold junction compensation matrix just like the NIST and NASA ones for even the cheap chinese ones and get down to much below 0.1K with them (assuming you use just the cables and not their plug)

Comment: @PlasmaHH  That's pretty much what I expected, but I'll keep searching for some kind of research or published data to be sure.  Plus I don't think I can do a good multi-point calibration with the equipment I have at home.

Comment: have a look (best in graphical form) of the cold junction compensation matrices that are currently used and get familiar with their nonlinearities

Comment: @PlasmaHH  I must admit I'm a bit confused... by "matrices" are you talking about something like [this](http://srdata.nist.gov/its90/type_k/0to300.html)?

Comment: yep, and have a look at what alloy they are for exactly, and try to replicate points from there for different couples you have around and you will see that they are all slightly different.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  I still don't see how that helps me.  In order to measure the temperature/voltage characteristic of a thermocouple, I'd need accurate temperature measurements... which is what I'm trying to get at in the first place.  As for your suggestion of comparing different thermocouples, that wouldn't tell me how far any of them are from the standard.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to setup some 4 wire pt1000 sensor for a calibration environment that is good to 0.1K or below accuracy. single point is just not going to cut it, which you can see easily when you graph the nist tables.